# Add time offset in EPG xmlTV file

Tags: php, xml, timezone-offset

I have found an EPG xmlTV file from my tv provider (Ziggo in The Netherlands).

This is great because I can directly implement the link within my EMBY live tv guide. There's only one problem...

All programs are set +1 hour. I have tried to change local settings and even time settings within my Synology NAS but that didn't work.

I also have tried to add a time offset within my own created xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site generator-info-name="WebGrab+Plus/w MDB &amp; REX Postprocess -- version 1.1.1/50 -- Jan van Straaten" site="ziggo.nl">
  <channels>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nederland 1" xmltv_id="Nederland 1">Nederland 1</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nederland 2" xmltv_id="Nederland 2">Nederland 2</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nederland 3" xmltv_id="Nederland 3">Nederland 3</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Ziggo TV" xmltv_id="Ziggo TV">Ziggo TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Etalagekanaal" xmltv_id="Etalagekanaal">Etalagekanaal</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Eventkanaal" xmltv_id="Eventkanaal">Eventkanaal</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Comedy Central/Kindernet" xmltv_id="Comedy Central/Kindernet">Comedy Central/Kindernet</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nickelodeon" xmltv_id="Nickelodeon">Nickelodeon</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Disney Channel" xmltv_id="Disney Channel">Disney Channel</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Discovery Channel" xmltv_id="Discovery Channel">Discovery Channel</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="National Geographic Channel" xmltv_id="National Geographic Channel">National Geographic Channel</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TLC" xmltv_id="TLC">TLC</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Eurosport" xmltv_id="Eurosport">Eurosport</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="MTV" xmltv_id="MTV">MTV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="13TH STREET" xmltv_id="13TH STREET">13TH STREET</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="24 Kitchen" xmltv_id="24 Kitchen">24 Kitchen</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Een" xmltv_id="Een">Een</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Canvas" xmltv_id="Canvas">Canvas</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="NostalgieNet" xmltv_id="NostalgieNet">NostalgieNet</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BravaNL" xmltv_id="BravaNL">BravaNL</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Family 7" xmltv_id="Family 7">Family 7</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Disney XD" xmltv_id="Disney XD">Disney XD</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Journaal 24" xmltv_id="Journaal 24">Journaal 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Politiek 24" xmltv_id="Politiek 24">Politiek 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="CNN International" xmltv_id="CNN International">CNN International</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BBC World News" xmltv_id="BBC World News">BBC World News</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Euronews" xmltv_id="Euronews">Euronews</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Aljazeera International" xmltv_id="Aljazeera International">Aljazeera International</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BBC 1" xmltv_id="BBC 1">BBC 1</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BBC 2" xmltv_id="BBC 2">BBC 2</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="ARD" xmltv_id="ARD">ARD</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="ZDF" xmltv_id="ZDF">ZDF</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="NDR" xmltv_id="NDR">NDR</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="WDR" xmltv_id="WDR">WDR</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="RTL Television" xmltv_id="RTL Television">RTL Television</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Sat. 1" xmltv_id="Sat. 1">Sat. 1</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Arte" xmltv_id="Arte">Arte</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV5 Monde" xmltv_id="TV5 Monde">TV5 Monde</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="France 2" xmltv_id="France 2">France 2</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Rai Uno" xmltv_id="Rai Uno">Rai Uno</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TVE" xmltv_id="TVE">TVE</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TRT International" xmltv_id="TRT International">TRT International</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Promo Erotiek pakket" xmltv_id="Promo Erotiek pakket">Promo Erotiek pakket</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Goed TV" xmltv_id="Goed TV">Goed TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Zenderoverzicht" xmltv_id="Zenderoverzicht">Zenderoverzicht</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Omroep Zeeland" xmltv_id="Omroep Zeeland">Omroep Zeeland</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Flevoland" xmltv_id="TV Flevoland">TV Flevoland</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Drenthe" xmltv_id="TV Drenthe">TV Drenthe</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Noord" xmltv_id="TV Noord">TV Noord</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Omrop Fryslân" xmltv_id="Omrop Fryslân">Omrop Fryslân</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Oost" xmltv_id="TV Oost">TV Oost</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="L1 Limburg" xmltv_id="L1 Limburg">L1 Limburg</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Utrecht" xmltv_id="TV Utrecht">TV Utrecht</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Gelderland" xmltv_id="TV Gelderland">TV Gelderland</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Omroep Brabant TV" xmltv_id="Omroep Brabant TV">Omroep Brabant TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="AT5" xmltv_id="AT5">AT5</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Noord-Holland" xmltv_id="TV Noord-Holland">TV Noord-Holland</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Rijnmond" xmltv_id="TV Rijnmond">TV Rijnmond</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV West" xmltv_id="TV West">TV West</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="RTL 4" xmltv_id="RTL 4">RTL 4</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="RTL 5" xmltv_id="RTL 5">RTL 5</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="SBS 6" xmltv_id="SBS 6">SBS 6</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="RTL 7" xmltv_id="RTL 7">RTL 7</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="MGM Movie Channel" xmltv_id="MGM Movie Channel">MGM Movie Channel</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TCM" xmltv_id="TCM">TCM</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Crime and Investigation Network" xmltv_id="Crime and Investigation Network">Crime and Investigation Network</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Zone Reality" xmltv_id="Zone Reality">Zone Reality</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Humor TV 24" xmltv_id="Humor TV 24">Humor TV 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="101 TV" xmltv_id="101 TV">101 TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="OUTTV" xmltv_id="OUTTV">OUTTV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Best 24" xmltv_id="Best 24">Best 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Animal Planet HD" xmltv_id="Animal Planet HD">Animal Planet HD</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Travel Channel" xmltv_id="Travel Channel">Travel Channel</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Holland Doc 24" xmltv_id="Holland Doc 24">Holland Doc 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Cultura 24" xmltv_id="Cultura 24">Cultura 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nick Jr." xmltv_id="Nick Jr.">Nick Jr.</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Cartoon Network" xmltv_id="Cartoon Network">Cartoon Network</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="JimJam" xmltv_id="JimJam">JimJam</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Boomerang" xmltv_id="Boomerang">Boomerang</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Baby TV" xmltv_id="Baby TV">Baby TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Zappelin 24 / ZaPP 24" xmltv_id="Zappelin 24 / ZaPP 24">Zappelin 24 / ZaPP 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="SLAM!TV" xmltv_id="SLAM!TV">SLAM!TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Lite TV" xmltv_id="Lite TV">Lite TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="VH-1" xmltv_id="VH-1">VH-1</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="VH-1 Classic" xmltv_id="VH-1 Classic">VH-1 Classic</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="192TV" xmltv_id="192TV">192TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TV Oranje" xmltv_id="TV Oranje">TV Oranje</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Eurosport 2" xmltv_id="Eurosport 2">Eurosport 2</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="CNBC" xmltv_id="CNBC">CNBC</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Weer en Verkeer" xmltv_id="Weer en Verkeer">Weer en Verkeer</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BBC Three" xmltv_id="BBC Three">BBC Three</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BBC Four" xmltv_id="BBC Four">BBC Four</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BBC HD" xmltv_id="BBC HD">BBC HD</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="BBC Entertainment" xmltv_id="BBC Entertainment">BBC Entertainment</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="PassieTV / Dusk!" xmltv_id="PassieTV / Dusk!">PassieTV / Dusk!</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Veronica/Disney XD" xmltv_id="Veronica/Disney XD">Veronica/Disney XD</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Net 5" xmltv_id="Net 5">Net 5</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="RTL 8" xmltv_id="RTL 8">RTL 8</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="RTL Crime" xmltv_id="RTL Crime">RTL Crime</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Syfy Universal" xmltv_id="Syfy Universal">Syfy Universal</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Investigation Discovery" xmltv_id="Investigation Discovery">Investigation Discovery</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Comedy Central Family" xmltv_id="Comedy Central Family">Comedy Central Family</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Comedy Central Extra" xmltv_id="Comedy Central Extra">Comedy Central Extra</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="RTL Lounge" xmltv_id="RTL Lounge">RTL Lounge</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="FOXlife" xmltv_id="FOXlife">FOXlife</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="E! Entertainment" xmltv_id="E! Entertainment">E! Entertainment</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Discovery Science" xmltv_id="Discovery Science">Discovery Science</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Discovery World" xmltv_id="Discovery World">Discovery World</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nat Geo Wild" xmltv_id="Nat Geo Wild">Nat Geo Wild</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="History HD" xmltv_id="History HD">History HD</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="History" xmltv_id="History">History</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Mezzo" xmltv_id="Mezzo">Mezzo</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Disney Junior" xmltv_id="Disney Junior">Disney Junior</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nick Toons" xmltv_id="Nick Toons">Nick Toons</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Nick Hits" xmltv_id="Nick Hits">Nick Hits</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Pebble TV" xmltv_id="Pebble TV">Pebble TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="MTV Live HD" xmltv_id="MTV Live HD">MTV Live HD</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="MTV Brand New" xmltv_id="MTV Brand New">MTV Brand New</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="MTV Music 24" xmltv_id="MTV Music 24">MTV Music 24</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="538" xmltv_id="538">538</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="ESPN America" xmltv_id="ESPN America">ESPN America</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Motors TV" xmltv_id="Motors TV">Motors TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Film1 Premiere" xmltv_id="Film1 Premiere">Film1 Premiere</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Film1 Action" xmltv_id="Film1 Action">Film1 Action</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Film1 Family" xmltv_id="Film1 Family">Film1 Family</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Film1 Festival" xmltv_id="Film1 Festival">Film1 Festival</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Film1 Series" xmltv_id="Film1 Series">Film1 Series</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Sport1 Select (HD)" xmltv_id="Sport1 Select (HD)">Sport1 Select (HD)</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Sport1 Voetbal" xmltv_id="Sport1 Voetbal">Sport1 Voetbal</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Sport1 Golf" xmltv_id="Sport1 Golf">Sport1 Golf</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Sport1 Tennis" xmltv_id="Sport1 Tennis">Sport1 Tennis</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Sport1 Extra - 1" xmltv_id="Sport1 Extra - 1">Sport1 Extra - 1</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Sport1 Extra - 2" xmltv_id="Sport1 Extra - 2">Sport1 Extra - 2</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Eredivisie Live 1" xmltv_id="Eredivisie Live 1">Eredivisie Live 1</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Eredivisie Live 2" xmltv_id="Eredivisie Live 2">Eredivisie Live 2</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Eredivisie Live 3" xmltv_id="Eredivisie Live 3">Eredivisie Live 3</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Eredivisie Live 4" xmltv_id="Eredivisie Live 4">Eredivisie Live 4</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Private Spice" xmltv_id="Private Spice">Private Spice</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="PassieXXX" xmltv_id="PassieXXX">PassieXXX</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Dusk!" xmltv_id="Dusk!">Dusk!</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="OUTTV" xmltv_id="OUTTV">OUTTV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="X-MO" xmltv_id="X-MO">X-MO</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Euro D" xmltv_id="Euro D">Euro D</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="ATV Avrupa" xmltv_id="ATV Avrupa">ATV Avrupa</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="TGRT EU" xmltv_id="TGRT EU">TGRT EU</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Samanyolu Avrupa" xmltv_id="Samanyolu Avrupa">Samanyolu Avrupa</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Euro Star" xmltv_id="Euro Star">Euro Star</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Show TV" xmltv_id="Show TV">Show TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Haberturk" xmltv_id="Haberturk">Haberturk</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="KralTV" xmltv_id="KralTV">KralTV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Planet TÃ¼rk" xmltv_id="Planet TÃ¼rk">Planet TÃ¼rk</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="LIG TV" xmltv_id="LIG TV">LIG TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Turk Max" xmltv_id="Turk Max">Turk Max</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Zee TV" xmltv_id="Zee TV">Zee TV</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="SET Asia" xmltv_id="SET Asia">SET Asia</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Zee Cinema" xmltv_id="Zee Cinema">Zee Cinema</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="SET MAX" xmltv_id="SET MAX">SET MAX</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Phoenix CNE" xmltv_id="Phoenix CNE">Phoenix CNE</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="Phoenix Infonews" xmltv_id="Phoenix Infonews">Phoenix Infonews</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="HBO" xmltv_id="HBO">HBO</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="HBO 2" xmltv_id="HBO 2">HBO 2</channel>
    <channel update="i" site="ziggo.nl" offset="-1" site_id="HBO 3" xmltv_id="HBO 3">HBO 3</channel>
  </channels>
</site>
```

Again... that did not work eather. It just outputs the normal (wrong) times.

Then I tried to implment the XML content within a PHP file so I could use str_replace like this:

```
<?php

$xml_ziggo  = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://d52255a1.static.ziggozakelijk.nl/xmltv.xml'));
$xml_ziggo  = str_replace('&quot; stop=&quot;',' -0100&quot; stop=&quot;',$xml_ziggo);
$xml_ziggo  = str_replace('&quot; channel=&quot;',' -0100&quot; channel=&quot;',$xml_ziggo);

echo $xml_ziggo;

?>
```

But that also did not work.

Can anyone please help me with this stupid but oh so big problem?

T.i.a.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably safer to use something like SimpleXML to manipulate the file, it comes down to...

```
$xml_ziggo  = simplexml_load_file('http://d52255a1.static.ziggozakelijk.nl/xmltv.xml');

foreach ( $xml_ziggo->programme as $programme ) {
    $programme['start'] = $programme['start'].' -0100';
    $programme['stop'] = $programme['stop'].' -0100';
}
echo $xml_ziggo->asXML();
```

This loads the XML, goes through each programme listing and adds ' -0100' to the attributes you want to change.

The result is...

```
  <programme start="20180318000000 -0100" stop="20180319000000 -0100" channel="nickmusic">
```

Comment: You my man... Are a live saver! Works like a charme! I can't REP you because I have to less reps myself. I realy would like to show my apriceation. Thanks so much.